# ESC motor calibrated, but still beeping and not responding

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, brushless-dc-motor, calibration

I am using this motor called [abcGoodefg RC 2200Kv brushless motor](http://www.abcgoodefg.com/abcgoodefg-rc-2200kv-brushless-motor-2212-6-with-30a-brushless-esc-set-accessories-kit-mount-for-rc-plane-quadcopter-helicopter-aircraft.html). At first, when we followed the sample code [on this website](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-brushless-motor-control-tutorial-esc-bldc/), things went well. But when we changed 1000 and 2000 to 10 and 20, respectively, our motor wouldn’t respond properly.

We then tried to properly follow the calibration procedure (as in, set throttle to high with Arduino connected and battery disconnected). Once we connect our NiMH Tenergy battery, we hear two beeps (one low, then one high), we then set our throttle to 0, but we still keep hearing one beep per one second. The beeps eventually die off, but we never receive confirmation beeps (1-2-3, then 2-2).

Can someone explain what is going on, and how to fix it? Could it be the issue with the battery? Or the motor itself? Please help! We need to get this solved for our final project!

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo ESC;     // create servo object to control the ESC
int potValue;  // value from the analog pin
void setup() {
  // Attach the ESC on pin 9
  ESC.attach(9,1000,2000); // (pin, min pulse width, max pulse width in microseconds) 
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  potValue = analogRead(A0);   // reads the value of the potentiometer (value between 0 and 1023)
  Serial.println(potValue);
  potValue = map(potValue, 0, 1023, 0, 180);   // scale it to use it with the servo library (value between 0 and 180)
  ESC.write(potValue);    // Send the signal to the ESC
}
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. I suggest that you add the code extract into your question so we don't have to follow links (which may die) to understand your question. Use the `{}` code tag to format it properly. One obvious question you need to explain: *"But when we changed 1000 and 2000 to 10 and 20, respectively, our motor wouldn’t respond properly."* Well if they worked why did you change them and if the new ones didn't work why didn't you change them back? A second question: is your error beep code not listed in the user manual?

Comment: Regarding the user manual, I could not find a proper pdf version of it or whatsoever.

Comment: Lesson #1: Do not buy things for which no datasheet or documentation are available.

Comment: Why did you "change 1000 and 2000 to 10 and 20"? The 1 - 2ms pulse timing is standard for most ESCs - which are you using?

Comment: _"but we still keep hearing one beep per one second." - that means the ESC is not receiving a valid signal (perhaps the pulse is too short). _"The beeps eventually die off"_ - perhaps your battery is flat? Did the ESC include programming instructions? I suggest you buy or make a [servo tester](http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/servo-tester.html) and try operating the ESC/motor with that first.